# Toolbar title first letter other color

Tags: java, android, title, toolbar, textcolor

I want my toolbar to have a colored title. That's not the problem. But how can I achieve that the first letter of the tile e.g. is black and the rest white?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One one could be to use `Html.fromHtml` to change the font's color of the two part of the String. E.g.

```
String first = "<font color='#FF000000'>F</font>";
String rest = "<font color='#FFFFFFFF'>irst</font>";
setTitle(Html.fromHtml(first + rest));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

```
SpannableString title = new SpannableString("Title text");
title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, 1, 0);
title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 1, title.length(), 0);
setTitle(title);
```